# libGDX - how to use 3D object indicating direction in 3D space?

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, libgdx, direction

I use libGDX for a 3D game. In this game an **3D arrow should indicate a certain direction** in 3D space. As the player is moving, the direction of the 3D arrow is updated for every frame.

I want to place the arrow in the direction, the camera is looking **3 units before the camera**, so that the arrow is always visible. Therefore I added the camera direction to the current camera position and used this as translation part for the arrow. The direction is calculated by substracting the arrow position from the target.

All this works fine, the arrow is displayed at the right position and it moves. The problem is, it **sometimes points to the target, and sometimes not**.

Here my code:

```
Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(1, 1, 10);
Vector3 cameraPosition = gameController.getCamera().position.cpy();
Vector3 cameraDirection = gameController.getCamera().direction.cpy();
Vector3 up = gameController.getCamera().up.cpy();

Vector3 arrowPosition = cameraDirection.scl(3).add(cameraPosition);
Vector3 arrowDirection = targetPosition.cpy();
arrowDirection = arrowDirection.sub(arrowPosition).nor();

Matrix4 transformationMatrix = new Matrix4();

// calculate orthogonal up vector
up.crs(arrowDirection).crs(arrowDirection);

arrowModel.transform = transformationMatrix.setToLookAt(arrowDirection,
    up).trn(arrowPosition);
```

To avoid that the vectors are calculated wrong, some debug lines were added:

```
modelBuilder.begin();
MeshPartBuilder partBuilder = modelBuilder.part("lines", GL20.GL_LINES,
    Usage.Position,
    new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)));
Vector3 linePos = arrowPosition.cpy();
partBuilder.line(linePos.cpy().add(arrowDirection), linePos);
partBuilder.line(linePos.cpy().add(up), linePos);
debugModel = new ModelInstance(modelBuilder.end());
```

As a result, I see a correct **green line for the up vector** (current up vector of the camera), and a **green line pointing correctly to my target, the green cube**. The arrow does something other:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3638/2ka7kvvj_jpg.htm

In the picture the arrow is quite near the right direction (green line), there are other situations, where it points in the completely wrong direction.

I used quite a lot combinations of .translate, .trn, .setToLookAt, and .rotate but all of them showed similar, wrong results.

Do you have an idea what went wrong here?

Comment: Is the gameController.getCamera().direction normalized? If not, normalized it because you may not know how long cameraDirection.scl(3) will be.